# Read udp image in gluon mobile

Tags: mobile, gluon

Hi How to read a coded image in bytearrayinputstream on mobile gluon While android does not recognize the ImageIO.read () function and that bitmap does not exist sir gluon The image is sent in UDP

Comment: Can you show what you've done already?

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).